# why do Date.parse('2012-01-01') and Date.parse('1/1/2012') return different values?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

Verified across browsers (Firefox & Chrome) and across platforms (OSX & Linux):

```
> Date.parse('2012-01-01')
1325376000000
> Date.parse('1/1/2012')
1325394000000
```

Relevant:
https://github.com/portablemind/compass_agile_enterprise/wiki/Javascript-Date.parse-bug%3F

Comment: I'd be cautious about using the second format even if it seemed to work with the browsers you tested with, because for dates like "1/2/2012" - well, I read that as 1 Feb, but I gather Americans would take it as Jan 2 - browsers may or may not take the locale into account...

Comment: hard to be cautious about it if it is user input (which it was in my case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format 2012-01-01 is interpreted as ISO 8601 conformant, and the Z timezone (+00, Universal Time Coordinated) is implied. The format 1/1/2012, if accepted (this is implementation-dependent), is taken as local time.

To get more consistent results, use a library like Globalize.js.

Comment: Or you can just add Z to the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you add Z to the end, that will guarantee that you always mean UTC.

```
> Date.parse('2012-01-01')
1325376000000
> Date.parse('1/1/2012')
1325394000000
> Date.parse('1/1/2012 Z')
1325376000000
```

Comment: No, according to the ECMAScript standard, Date.parse() is required to parse ISO 8601 formats such as 2012-01-01Z with or without Z, but there is no requirement on recognizing other formats, such as 1/1/2012: “If the String does not conform to that [ISO 8601] format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics  or  implementation-specific  date  formats.”

Comment: All I'm saying is that, practically speaking, if you put the Z in, the browser knows for sure that you want a time in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code as below:

```
    var a = Date.parse('2012-01-01');
    var b = Date.parse('2012-01-01');
    var c = Date.parse('1/1/2012');

    alert( a + ' - ' + b + ' - ' + c );
```

And result is,

1325376000000 - 1325376000000 - 1325376000000

The reason why I have written same code for a and b is, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp says, Date.parse returns a millisecond value, whether time passes between those lines.

Im using Firefox 9.0.1, and the result is correct.

Comment: IE8 returns: NaN - NaN - 1325376000000
Safari 5.1.2 returns: NaN - NaN - 1325376000000